# Cocos2d-x v3 Change Sprite texture with animation slide in/out

Tags: cocos2d-x, sprite

I have a Sprite init with file name "blue.png", this is just create a simple rect with blue color.

```
mySpriteOne = Sprite::create("blue.png");
mySpriteOne->setPosition(Vec2(0,0));
mySpriteOne->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));
this->addChild(mySpriteOne,-1);
```

I will change Sprite image with this code

```
mySpriteOne->setTexture("red.png")
```

Now i want when change image it also has a transition slide to right or slide to left.
I just learning cocos3d for a few days, so this problem seems too hard for me.

Thank for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do what you want to do would be to run a moveTo or moveBy action, then to do a callback to change your texture, and run a moveTo action back to your original Position.

```
float slideTime = 2.0f;  // Time taken for slideIn/Out animation
auto originalPosition = mySpriteOne->getPosition();
auto slideOutChangeSequence = Sequence::create(
                              MoveTo::create(slideTime, vec2(-100, 100)),
                              callfunc_selector(MainScene::swapTextureCallback),
                              MoveTo::create(slideTime, originalPosition,
                              NULL);

mySpriteOne->runAction(slideOutChangeSequence);
```

It's bit late, but you have no answer yet, I hope this helps.